# My angularfire firebase re add when delete

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am struggling with a probably minor problem, but searches and work hasn't given me the clue i am looking for. Here is the deal :

When i call `$scope.postit.$remove(post);` where postit is a synced array to firebase and post the element object i want to remove, firebase is showing the deletion in the backend (object gets all red) but re-add the element automatically (same object with same key all-green doubles the about to be deleted object).

beside, i am adding and saving all right...

Note that my security parameters are from origin, all read and write permissions.

Thank you all

code (heavily reduced to essential) :

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="postitCtrl">
   <div class="postit" ng-repeat="post in postit">
      <div class="close" ng-click="postit.$remove(post);"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
      <div class="title">title</div>
      <div class="content">title</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);

app.controller("postitCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray,$location) {
  $scope.ref = new Firebase("https://postonit.firebaseio.com/postit");
  $scope.postit = $firebaseArray($scope.ref);
});
```

Same when i put the remove in a fonction of my controler.

Comment: You have code that has a problem. Unless you show us the code, it will be impossible to see what is going wrong. Please make sure that it is minimal (only has the minimum that is needed to show your problem) and complete (has everything that is needed to run it). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

So... actually i had a function calling a `$save()` at any click. I overlooked it because i would't think this would then duplicate the deleted object.

So, i just made sure my `$save()` wasn't called at the same moment as `$remove()` and i'm all set up now.

Thanks to all anyway